# too many values to unpack, in list comprehension

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I am pretty new to python.

here is my code:

```
parameters=['id','release_date','genre_ids','original_title','title',
       'popularity','vote_count','vote_average','original_language','adult']

[ids,release_dates,genre_ids,original_titles,titles,
popularities,vote_counts,vote_averages,languages,adult_bool]= \
[descriptions[i]['results'][0][parameter] for i in range(length) for 
parameter in parameters]
```

where descriptions is an array of JSON's, length is the number of JSON's, and parameters are the parameters I want to grab.

(here is a link to an example of those JSON's: [link](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=simpsons&api_key=4e22f5e8c4cd0dba1f0efee8b572a810), best to watch it with JSON viewer).

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\binyamine\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-2-7f9c71ad8dba>", line 3, in <module>
[descriptions[i]['results'][0][parameter] for i in range(length) for 
parameter in parameters]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

any idea why???
thanks a lot!!

Comment: So what's the output of `[descriptions[i]['results'][0][parameter] for i in range(length) for parameter in parameters]`?

Answer (score 0):

That comprehension produces a `list` with a length equal to the number of values in `parameters` multiplied by `length`. Since you're trying to unpack it into something that's the length of `parameters`, it will only work when `length` is `1`. Create and assign this comprehension to a new reference (e.g. `result = [descriptions[i]...)`) and print it out to see what it produces. You can then process it based on its actual structure (or fix it if it doesn't produce the result you were looking for).

Comment: got you, thanks!
I'll use a for loop and assign each iteration into [ids[i], release_dates[i], etc.] instead of [ids, release_dates, etc.]